# How can I "bubble up" events on nested Backbone collections?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a Backbone app that uses **nested collections** (at least that's how I think they're called).

In my particular case there are **tabs** and **subtabs**, and each tab (model) contains a collection of subtab (model).

For those who're more familiar with code, I'll write bellow my models and collections, and how subtabs are nested inside the tab model:

```
// Subtab Model
var Subtab = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { label: undefined }
});

// Subtabs Collection
var Subtabs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Subtab
});

// Tab Model
var Tab = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { label: undefined, subtabs: new Subtabs}
});

// Tabs Collection
var Tabs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Tab
});
```

Now, when I change a tab's attribute it fires the change event on the `Tab` model and also on the `Tabs` collection (quite normal, right?), but when I change a subtab's attribute, it fires the change event on the `Subtab` model and `Subtabs` collection (this is also normal) **but it doesn't bubble up to the `Tab` model (and to the `Tabs` collection).**

At least, I guess it should because a collection inside a model was changed and so the model was changed (but maybe I'm wrong and I'm not getting it).

**Any suggestion on how can I achieve this behavior with Backbone?**

Comment: trigger the event manually when you receive it

Comment: @CoryDanielson I imagined that the event needed to be triggered 'manually' but it didn't work, I got _RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded_.

Comment: Are you doing something with setTimeout? That's not an error I've ever gotten before while using Backbone

Comment: @CoryDanielson No, not at all!

Comment: I've never seen a call stack error happen from something non-asynchronous... something async has to be going on... is the event triggering a bunch of ajax calls? do you have a setInterval running at the same time? How big is the collection? What does this.subtabsChanged that you mentioned in the other comment do?

Comment: @ChrisX Usually "Maximum call stack size exceeded" is a strong indicator that you have infinite recursion going on. Could a change listener on your outer model be doing something that would trigger change on an inner model? Then the change events would loop around forever...

Answer (score 7):

A `change` event is triggered by Backbone when an attribute changes via `set`. The event is then also triggered on the collection, as you have seen. But, the value of your `subtabs` attribute is not changing at all, it is still the same object you created in `defaults`.  If you used `tab.set('subtabs', new Subtabs);` you would get a `change:subtabs` event, but you don't want to do that.

I think you would have to do something in your code to trigger a new event on your Tab model.

```
// Tab Model
var Tab = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { label: undefined, subtabs: new Subtabs},
    initialize: function(){
        // listen for change in subtabs collection.
        this.get('subtabs').on('change', this.subtabsChanged, this);
    },
    subtabsChanged: function(model) {
        // trigger new event.
        this.trigger('subtab:change', this, model);
    }
});
```

Then you could listen for the event:

```
tabs.on('subtab:change', function(tab, subtab) { 
    console.log(tab.get('label'));
    console.log(subtab.get('label'));
});
```

This will work, I think.  But I guess I am wondering why you would listen to your Tabs collection for a change in the Subtabs.  In most cases, it might be better to just listen for the change event on your Subtabs collection itself.

```
tab.get('subtabs').on('change', function(model){
    // do something with model, which is a Subtab.
});
```

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/phoenecke/DvHqH/1/

Comment: Based on your answer and with some changes to your code, I managed to trigger the original `change` event on the model. I was doing wrong binding the `change` event without any context `this.get('subtabs').on('change', this.subtabsChanged, this);` and I was getting an error _RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded_. So, `this` is the key.

Comment: what does this.subtabsChanged do?

Comment: @CoryDanielson Trigger an event on the Tab when something in the subtabs child collection changed...

Comment: @PaulHoenecke sorry, I was asking Chris X trying to figure out why he's getting the RangeError

Comment: @CoryDanielson as you can see, the `.subtabsChanged` is the handler for the change event when is triggered by the subtabs collection. This handler triggers the custom event `subtab:change` for a tab (model).

Comment: @CoryDanielson. Updated with jsFiddle. The stack size error is not in this code.

Comment: note, `listenTo()` might be preferred to `on()`.  http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo

Comment: re: "I am wondering why you would listen to your Tabs collection for a change in the Subtabs", one example might be when you have one View representing the contents of the Tabs and Subtabs collection...