# Backbone change event not firing when certain attributes are changed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-model

In my backbone application, I have a model that looks a little like this,

```
{  
    "id" : 145,
    "name" : "Group Number 1",
    "information" : "Some kind of blurb about group number 1",
    "members" : {[
       "id" : 1,  
       "first_name" : "John",
       "last_name" : "Doe",
       "email" : "johndoe@goog.ecom"
    ]}
}
```

Now if I run `this.model.get('members').add(newUser)` a new user gets added to the members collection within my model - however it does not fire a change event, why is this? Buy yet if I change the name of the model, then a change event is fired?

All this is done with a view that looks like this,

**Individual model view**

```
Views.OrganisationView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'div',
    className:'group group--panel col-sm-3',

    template : _.template( $('#tpl-single-group').html() ),

    events: {
        "click a[data-type=organisation], button[data-type=organisation]" : "edit",
        "click .js-delete-group" : "removeOrganisation",
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on("error", function(model, xhr, options){
            console.log(model, xhr, options);
            console.log(this);
        });
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.removeView);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template({
            group: this.model.toJSON()
        }));

        return this;
    },

    removeView: function() {
        this.remove();
    },

    removeOrganisation: function(e) {
        this.model.destory();
        this.remove();
    },

    edit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    Routes.Application.navigate('/organisation/edit/' + this.model.get('id'), { trigger: false } );
        var editClient = new Views.OrganisastionEditView({
            model: this.model
        });
    }

});
```

The second confusing thing that a request event gets thrown, (makes sense seen as though I am saving the model, but an error event gets thrown as well, but there are no errors the `xhr` and I am not currently validating the model?

Here is how I am saving the user to members collection in my model,

```
var member = new Pops.Models.User({ id: element.data('id') });
member.fetch({
    success:function() {
        self.model.get('members').add(member);
        var model = self.model;
        self.$('.search').hide();
        self.$('button').show();
        var projectMember = new Pops.Views.UserInitialsWithAdmin({
            model: member
        });
        self.model.save({validate:false});
        self.$('.search').parent().append( projectMember.render().el );
        self.$('.search').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: There is a bit of confusion with declaration of models and collections in your example. In a first example of object `members` attribute is another javascript object, not a `Backbone.Collection`, so I wonder how you calling `add` on it. And for your second issue - it's working as expected. `request` event will be thrown whenever `Backbone.sync` called (it is initiated by `model.fetch`). And if `$.ajax` fails it will call error callback.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming the first bit of code you've given is just a guideline of what a plain JSON representation of your model would look like, and that `members` is a real `Collection` with an `add` method available.)

In answer to the first question: change events are only fired when changing a model attribute using `set`. In your case, you're adding to the collection stored in the `members` attribute, but the `members` attribute still contains a reference to the same collection it did before, which means from Backbone's perspective this attribute has not changed. I would suggest attaching listeners directly to the `members` collection. Also see [How can I "bubble up" events on nested Backbone collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856614/how-can-i-bubble-up-events-on-nested-backbone-collections).

In general nesting models in Backbone is not straightforward, as [Jeremy Ashkenas has pointed out.](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model/issues/14#issuecomment-15687361) It's often better to keep models flat and store references to related models as arrays of ids, which can then be fetched as necessary.