# Backbonejs - How to listen to a change in a collection that is part of a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My app is made up of the following:

Collections:

- Sections
- Seats

Models:

- Seat
- Seating Chart
- Section

A SeatingChart has a `Sections` as an attribute

A `Sections` is a collection of `Section`

A `Section` has a `Seats` as an attribute

A `Seats` is a collection of `Seat`

Is there a way to, inside the `SeatingChart` listen to when a `Seat` is added to one of the `Section`s in the `SeatingChart`'s `Sections`?

Comment: You never said what's the relation between `SeatingChart` and these things but nesting is not supported dirctly in backbone, you'll have to use plugins like backbone relational or something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I "bubble up" events on nested Backbone collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856614/how-can-i-bubble-up-events-on-nested-backbone-collections)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you know Backbone does provide this functionality out of the box. So I'm going to assume that you'd like a suggestion of how to get this thing wired. The solution to follow is going to be specific to your design. For a generalization I suggest you look to Backbone Relational

You already put the first component of the solution which is to keep a reference to the collection you're tracking. This will come in handy as we move up the relationships.

But let's start at the bottom. The questions ask how to detect when a seat is added. So let's define the `Seats` collection:

```
var Seats = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.setupListeners();
  },

  setupListeners: function () {
    this.on('add', _.partial(this.bubbleAction, 'add'));
    this.on('remove', _.partial(this.bubbleAction, 'remove'));
  },

  bubbleAction: function (action, model) {
    this.trigger('seats-action' action, model);
  }
})
```

Now `Sections` would have to pickup the `Seats` action and bubble it up.

```
var Sections = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.setupListeners();
  },

  setupListeners: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.seats, 'seats-action', this.bubbleSeatsAction);
  },

  bubbleSeatsAction: function (action, model) {
    this.trigger('section:seats-action', this.sectionClass, action, model);
  }
})
```

And finally in your `SeatingChart` collection:

```
var SeatingChart = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.setupListeners();
  },

  setupListeners: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.sections, 'section:seats-action', this.handleSeatAction);
  },

  handleSeatAction: function (section, action, model) {
    ///Logic goes here to handle a seat action///
})
```